# using inline-block to truncate text in span breaks UI

Tags: css

I want to truncate the text and the alignment of the elements must be kept. And to truncate text in span, `display: inline-block` must be used. But using it breaks the UI.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlinph/9wdmnLv5/)

Code Snippets

HTML

```
<a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-circle bordered"></i>
<span class="bordered inline">{{text}}</span>
<i class="fa fa-times bordered"></i>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.inline {
  max-width: 137px !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Expected Output is to have the truncated text be aligned with the surrounding `<i></i>` tags.

Comment: How exactly does the UI break? What's the desired UI result?

Comment: Not so clear what you are asking for. Could you show by a picture?

Comment: adding `vertical-align: top` to `.inline{}` seems to work.

Comment: @Fran yeah. seems to 'kinda' work, since the borders are not aligned like in the 2nd output. But I think this is the closest one so far.

to others. updated fiddle and question

Comment: Could you the answer post how you solved it instead of updating the title/question as not seeing the solution is not helpful to future users coming here for a solution for the same/similar issue. You are also able to accept your own answers that solved your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fran suggested, adding `vertical-align: top` fixes the issue.

```
.inline {
  max-width: 137px !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Examples can be seen on this [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlinph/9wdmnLv5/). You may notice that even adding `vertical-align: top` doesn't really align the elements like in the 3rd example. But it is the closest answer for now.